# Has installing node.js corrupted my Mingw Bash?

Tags: windows, node.js, git-bash

After installing node on Windows 8.1, using the standard installer, calling `clear` in Git Bash gives an error:

`/bin/clear: line 4: //C: No such file or directory`

Editing the `clear` source to replace `$COMSPEC` with `cmd` makes it works again but seems like a hack.

How can I fix properly?

Comment: Got it working by adding `export COMSPEC="cmd"` to my `.bash_profile`, but this still seems like a hack.